# How to skip a file from executing in jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, jasmine

I am working on integration tests with jest where i have a 20 test files under a folder. I need to make sure three files in that folder need not to be executed while running the tests. i tried with **testPathIgnorePatterns** but it only works for folders and not for files. how to do that?

jest.config.js

```
/**
 * @file Jest Integration Test Configuration File
 */

module.exports = {
  roots: ['../../tests'],
  testRegex: '_*_integration.test.(js|ts|tsx)?$',
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsconfig: 'tsconfig.json',
    },
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'js'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['tests/api/modules/m3/sample.test.ts'],
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  reporters: [
    'default',
    [
      '../../node_modules/jest-html-reporter',
      {
        pageTitle: 'Integration Test Report',
        outputPath: 'tests/reports/integration-test-report.html',
        includeFailureMsg: true,
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

Comment: Why not change the name of the file, or move it into a lm e.g. samples directory and ignore that?

Comment: Nope,  that is not possible. following some standards over the project. so moving to a folder is not recommended @jonrsharpe

Comment: What standards? And not recommended !== not possible, is it really sensible to have a file that seems to be a test file but isn't (what *is* it)? It's clearly confusing the test discovery, but more importantly will probably confuse *people*.

Comment: @muthu how about renaming the files to `_integration.test.skip.js`

Comment: @Teneff thanks, this is what  i am looking for, can you please add as answer. will accept that

Comment: That's an answer? You told me you *couldn't* rename the file.

Answer (score 6):

How about using `--testPathIgnorePatterns` cli option?

`yarn test --testPathIgnorePatterns=user.test.ts`

If for multi files, can use below.

`yarn test --testPathIgnorePatterns=filename1 filename2`

Comment: They're already using testPathIgnorePatterns, and report that it matches directories not files; why would it be different in the CLI vs. the config file?

Answer (score 0):

For individual files to ignore from Jest coverage place the following line at the top

```
/* istanbul ignore file */
```

Ignore individual functions please past following above the function

```
/* istanbul ignore next */
const ignoreFunc =()=>{
 console.log('This function will be ignored from coverage')
}
```

Answer (score -5):

You can use the **`collectCoverageFrom`** parameter of Zest json like this,

```
collectCoverageFrom: ['path-to-file1','path-to-file2'],
```

Note: This option requires collectCoverage to be set to true or Jest to be invoked with `--coverage.`

Refer [documentation](https://jest-bot.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#collectcoveragefrom-array)

In documentation, they specified a pattern but it works file static file paths too.